# Jekyll/github pages issue: URL without trailing slash is loading an old/ out-of-date version of github site

Tags: html, github, jekyll, liquid, permalinks

I am running into an issue with our website, which is built using github & Jekyll. The web page that I am trying to load works **WITH** a trailing slash, but if you type it in to your browser **WITHOUT** a trailing slash, it pulls up an outdated version of the entire site. This is creating issues for our site visitors because they are getting outdated information when they look at this page.

Weirdly, it is only an issue on this one page, not on any other page on the site.

[outercoast.org/year](http://outercoast.org/year)   (this is the url **WITHOUT** trailing slash is pulling up an out-of-date version- note that the top menu is also different and out of date from the rest of the site)

[outercoast.org/year/](http://outercoast.org/year/)  (this url **WITH** trailing slash is pulling up the correct version)

I tried some different things, like setting up a manual redirect and playing with permalink settings, but no luck.

Here is the repo: https://github.com/javbotero/Outer-Coast

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to fix this issue? Thanks so much for taking a look!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I think this is related to https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/, more explicit `permalink: /:path/` in your _config.yml file somehow. Cannot test it locally because my Chrome browser redirects me to /year/, just try out `permalink: /:collection/` also localhost:4000 shows the correct content.

Comment: What does happen when you completely remove the permalink from _config.yml - as far as I could see the only page in the /year folder is the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two pages :

- **year.html** with `permalink: /year/`, it can be reached at http://outercoast.org/year/
- **year/index.html** with `permalink: /year`, it can be reached at http://outercoast.org/year.html and http://outercoast.org/year

You will have to choose one of those pages, and I think that you can delete **year/index.html**.

The fact that http://outercoast.org/year returns an old version comes from your Amazon hosting. It seems that they are not invalidating cache.

The full http response from firefox network panel is :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: qib+GnWWIIct1mrEC/dtF/NgJeZ8dWr4yH8Nc/a+RieFAKT0VEh2h40fSMJp+IyaXiAw+rv7hbI=
x-amz-request-id: ED0E3EE0EBF5D323
Date: Sat, 25 Jan 2020 21:26:18 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 23 Nov 2019 01:02:04 GMT
ETag: "c8c259c6d791a7f42f264832b97dbd42"
Content-Type: 
Content-Length: 11060
Server: AmazonS3
```

Comment: Any ideas on how to get amazon cache invalidation working ? Thank you all so much for your thoughts ! This is really so helpful.

Comment: No idea, but you can ask on SO. You can also ensure that you delete all the files before republishing on S3.

Comment: What was the solution to this problem ?

Comment: I looked through our amazon aws and found that there was an old version of the file that was outdated. I deleted that and it fixed the problem!